# Add Login Options using password and email other than google authentication in Next js using Next Auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am very confused in how Next Auth works I have this api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { ConnectToDB } from '@utils/database';
import User from '@models/user';
const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session }) {
      // store the user id from MongoDB to session
    const sessionUser = await User.findOne({ email: session.user.email });
    session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();
    return session;
    },
    async signIn({ account, profile, user, credentials }) {
      try {
        await ConnectToDB();

        // check if user already exists
        const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: profile.email });

        // if not, create a new document and save user in MongoDB
        if (!userExists) {
          await User.create({
            email: profile.email,
            name: profile.name.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase(),
            image: profile.picture,
          });
        }

        return true
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error checking if user exists: ", error.message);
        return false
      }
    },
  }
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Mt User Schema is this models/user.js

```
import { Schema, models, model } from 'mongoose';

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, 'Email already exists'],
    required: [true, 'Please add an email'],
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  is_verfied: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  parameters: {
    type: Array,
    default: [],
  },
  forgot_password_token: String,
  forgot_password_token_expires: Date,
  verify_token: String,
  verify_token_expires: Date,
});

const User = models.User || model('User', UserSchema);

export default User;
```

I am able to store the user data into database and sign up when I use the SignIn from next-auth, also able to useSession to get the currently logged in user data, here is that signin page

```
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { signIn, getProviders, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';
const SignInPage = () => {
  const {data: session} = useSession();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [providers, setProviders] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();
  const setUpProviders = async () => {
    const response = await getProviders();
    setProviders(response);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setUpProviders();
  }, [session])
  const signInCred = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/users/signin', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({email, password})
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    if (data.error) {
      alert(data.error);
    }
    else {
      alert('Sign up successful');
      router.push('/admin');
    }
  }
  const checkForm = () => {
    console.log({email, password});
    if (email === '') {
      alert('Email is required');
    }
    else if (email.indexOf('@') === -1 || email.indexOf('.') === -1) {
      alert('Email is invalid');
    }
    else if (password === '') {
      alert('Password is required');
    }
    else {
      signInCred();
    }
  }
  const SubmitEvent = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkForm();
  };
  if (!session) {
  return (
    <main className='flex items-center justify-center'>
        <div className="bg-white p-8 rounded shadow-md w-full md:w-96">
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4 text-center">Sign In to Gehu Sports</h2>
        <form>
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" className="w-full border rounded py-2 px-3" onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}} />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label htmlFor="password" className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" className="w-full border rounded py-2 px-3" onChange={(e)=>{setPassword(e.target.value)}} />
          </div>
          <button onClick={(e)=>{SubmitEvent(e)}} className="w-full bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded">Sign In</button>
        </form>
        <div className="mt-4 text-center">
          <p className="text-gray-500 text-sm">Or sign up with</p>
          {providers && Object.values(providers).map((provider) => {
            return (
              <button onClick={() => signIn(provider.id)} className="bg-red-500 text-white py-2 px-4 mt-2 rounded" key={provider.name}>{provider.name}</button>
            )
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="mt-4 text-center">
          <Link href={'/admin/signup'} className="text-gray-500 text-sm">New in Here? <span className="text-blue-500">Sign Up</span></Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
        }
  else {
    router.push('/admin');
    return (
      <div></div>
    )
  }
};

export default SignInPage;
```

On clicking the Google I am able to login but I want the user to login with email and password as well.
As you can see I have also added an api/users/signin route here

```
import { ConnectToDB } from "@utils/database";
import User from "@models/user";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

ConnectToDB();

export async function POST(NextRequest) {
  try {
    const reqBody = await NextRequest.json();
    const { email, password } = reqBody;
    console.log(reqBody);
    const userExist = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!userExist) {
      return NextResponse.json({error: 'User does not Exist', success: false}, {status: 400});
    }
    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, userExist.password);
    if (!validPassword) {
      return NextResponse.json({error: 'Invalid Password', success: false}, {status: 400});
    }
    return NextResponse.json({message: "User Logged In Successfully", success: true}, {status: 201});
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({error: error.message, success: false}, {status: 500});
  }
}
```

It just checks and accepts, but doesn't login, please help me add this feature as well.

I tried a lot of tutorials but nothing helped me understand it, please help me.